# From where should I can download SharePoint 2003 server setup?

Tags: windows-7

somehow i Need to configure the ShtrePoint 2003 server with Windows 7. From where should I can download SharePoint 2003 set up ? Does is compatible with Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not compatible with Windows 7. You can contact Microsoft to get it. If your company has a volumne licensing agreement with MS, you should still be able to get it on the VL site : https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx